# Where did the Greek word diaballein got it's meaning from accusing and divide from?

Tags: terminology, etymology, greek

διαβάλλειν (dia-ballein)
"Dia" means through (by the way of; or from one end or side of something to the other (across); or between) and "ballein" means throwing.

Now online there are two descriptions that I found most often to describe the meaning of this word:

1. throwing across; slander, accusing
2. to cast apart; to throw apart, or to scatter.

Looking at the pure etymology of this word; how did the word dia-ballein transform from 'through throwing' into something accusatory or divided?

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question ? Right now it is incomprehensible, at least for me.

Comment: It's like the expression "throw accusations/insults/etc. at someone".

Comment: Latin has a similar case where *traducere* (literally "to lead across") has given rise to "to parade [something/someone]" > "to expose to public ridicule" > "to defame".

Answer (score -2):

***dia*** comes from { *di > dy > du* } , meaning: *duo, two, 2*, in contrast to  { bi > by > [b:u] } which are already (in some manner) split, but kept together in parallel. Therefore as a logismus one stands like something split in origin; in two, and the other: brought in parallel.

For instance: ***dia***gonal, would mean to take a route which splits some existing gamma or angle in two parts.

So, dia depending on the notion it is applied to tends to signify a second hand, route, way; in contrast to a, common; straight; direct; ordinary, or conventional preexisting way.

Herein **διαβάλλειν** would mean "to throw over" but that's only because of gravity and because while standing on the ground - you cannot, throw under. This expression is however capable of covering every parable-like throw, between two points which are invisibly connected by the shortest path between them.

Comment: taqiatvllashkinenanenngojetaqi